# traefik - basic auth for frontend via key/value store

Tags: consul, traefik

How can I set basic auth for frontend via key/value store likes the label "traefik.frontend.auth.basic" for docker provider.

I checked codes in [this file](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/templates/kv.tmpl) and it might be not supported now.

I think it's useful, I'm trying to implement in my fork, any suggestions?